# How to cut a date's schedule and keep POSIXct format?

Tags: r, date, time

I'm having trouble cutting a date (Y-m-d H:M:S) to keep only the time (H:M) while keeping the POSIXct format. I've tried several cutting commands but the object becomes "chr" instead of "POSIXct". For example, I have :

```
time <- Sys.time()
time
[1] "2024-01-13 20:22:48 CET"
```

and

```
str(time)
POSIXct[1:1], format: "2024-01-13 20:22:48"
```

which is normal.

But, how can I keep only "20:22" (HH:MM) with the POSIXct format ?

Many thanks

Comment: POSIXct is basically a number of seconds since January 1, 1970, so you can't really just drop the date part.  What's your use case, what are your plans with those values? `hms` can be useful (`hms::as_hms(Sys.time())`), but it's based on `difftime`.

Comment: I agree with  @margusl. This is not possible. There are workarounds like adding a fixed date etc.. but we have to know what you really want to achieve!

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I try to use the library `gganimate`, for exemple `map_with_animation <- map_with_data + transition_time(horaire2) + ggtitle('Horaire : {frame_time}', subtitle = 'Frame {frame} of {nframes}')` but I wanted to change the value of `{frame_time}` by a HH:MM instead of a complete date. I followed this tutorial: https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/220339/time-maps-tutorial-v2.html?sequence=3

Comment: So just a string representation for lables?  When converting to string with `format()` or  `strftime()` , you can control output through format string, e.g.  `strftime(Sys.time(), "%H:%M")` , check `?strftime` for more specifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a subclass of POSIXct. Also define every operation on it wanted. Here we only define a constructor and `format` (which is used by `print`).

```
as.hmct <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.hmct")
as.hmct.POSIXct <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = c("hmct", class(x)))
format.hmct <- function(x, ...) format(.POSIXct(x), "%H:%M") 

# test it
tt <- as.POSIXct("2024-01-14 13:23:26")

tt2 <- as.hmct(tt); tt2
## [1] "13:23"

as.hmct(tt2 + 60) # one minute later
## [1] "13:24"
```